# Determining appropriate distribution to describe wind speed data

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

[image]

Hey, I have a dataset of hourly wind speed data and according to literature, the weibull distribution is best suited for this case, however when I fit this distribution to the data, according to the diagram it does not quite show that this distribution quite fits my data. How would I know when a distribution has fitted the dataset?

Comment: Try QQ plot against the distribution of choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weibull distribution would make sense for capturing the shape of a unimodal distribution of wind speeds, in which case the green density histogram of the observed wind speeds would have a single hump and the fitted Weibull density curve would approximate the shape of the histogram well. See Figure 5 in this article for an illustration of a density histogram of wind speeds that is approximated well by a Weibull density curve: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/aade/a28abb7bb3784b69961a09be3fc79be9756d.pdf.

The figure you attached here shows a large spike in the density histogram of observed wind speeds near zero and another one at about 7.5. So you may need a mixture of Weibull distributions to capture the bimodality of the histogram of the observed wind speeds.  (You should actually check whether that large spike near zero includes only zero wind speeds or some small non-zero wind speeds as well. If all speeds there are zero, then you may be dealing with zero-inflation.) Note that there is a minor third hump in the green density histogram, but it's really small so you could probably ignore it.

This article discusses mixtures of Weibull distributions: https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/JAMC-D-11-0231.1. 
From what I can tell, there is no code to go with the article. At least the article demostrates that other people have considered mixtures of Weibull distributions when modeling the distribution of wind speeds. (Your data are likely highly correlated over time, which may further complicate matters.)

However, R has some functionality for fitting such a mixture to your data through packages such as **mixtools** and **mixdist**.

Comment: The values are really zero in the dataset, however I adjusted it to be 0.00000001 as matlab does not consider 0 a positive number to implement the weibull distribution.

Comment: That suggests that a zero inflated Weibull distribution might work. Not sure whether Matlab can fit something like this though.